# LateInitializationError: Field 'annotationAst' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, dart-null-safety

I upgrade my packages using `dart pub outdated --mode=null-safety` command. after updating my packages I got this error while running `dart migrate` to migrate my code to null-safety.
also when I tried to run  `flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs` command for `moor` database.

I have no clue where this error is coming from and my codebase is really big to search for any initialization or annotation

Why does this issue happen and How can I solve that?

```
LateInitializationError: Field 'annotationAst' has not been initialized.
#0      ElementAnnotationImpl.annotationAst (package:analyzer/src/dart/element/element.dart)
#1      ConstantEvaluationEngine.computeDependencies (package:analyzer/src/dart/constant/evaluation.dart:336:39)
#2      _ConstantWalker._computeDependencies (package:analyzer/src/dart/constant/compute.dart:75:22)
#3      _ConstantNode.computeDependencies (package:analyzer/src/dart/constant/compute.dart:43:19)
#4      Node.getDependencies (package:analyzer/src/summary/link.dart:148:40)
#5      DependencyWalker.walk.strongConnect (package:analyzer/src/summary/link.dart:53:40)
#6      DependencyWalker.walk (package:analyzer/src/summary/link.dart:119:18)
#7      computeConstants (package:analyzer/src/dart/constant/compute.dart:26:14)
#8      LibraryAnalyzer._computeConstants (package:analyzer/src/dart/analysis/library_analyzer.dart:250:5)
#9      LibraryAnalyzer.analyzeSync (package:analyzer/src/dart/analysis/library_analyzer.dart:135:5)
#10     LibraryAnalyzer.analyze (package:analyzer/src/dart/analysis/library_analyzer.dart:103:12)
#11     AnalysisDriver._computeAnalysisResult.<anonymous closure> (package:analyzer/src/dart/analysis/driver.dart:1624:63)
#12     PerformanceLog.run (package:analyzer/src/dart/analysis/performance_logger.dart:32:15)
#13     AnalysisDriver._computeAnalysisResult (package:analyzer/src/dart/analysis/driver.dart:1600:20)
#14     AnalysisDriver._computeErrors (package:analyzer/src/dart/analysis/driver.dart:1678:26)
#15     AnalysisDriver.performWork (package:analyzer/src/dart/analysis/driver.dart:1301:20)
#16     AnalysisDriverScheduler._run (package:analyzer/src/dart/analysis/driver.dart:2334:24)
```

Comment: Its clearly saying that 'annotation` has not been initialized.

Comment: I don't have anything named `annotation` or `annotationAst` in my code!

Comment: there are multiple lines containing `annotationAst` only in the flutter itself path: /home/ns/snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/analyzer-1.7.1/lib/src